# jQuery + .each() + .post()... running synchronously?

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table. This table has several rows. I am running jQuery code which scans the table, and for each row, runs a POST request. Below is the code I am using...

First, we setup the table, and fetch some data from it:

```
$target = this.$target;

var process = true,
    eventID = $target.data('event'),
    address = $target.data('href');
```

Then I iterate over all the rows with `.each()`

```
$target.find('.row').each(function()
{
    var $fa = $(this).find('.fa');

    if (process)
    {
        var input = {
            'eventID': eventID,
            'userID': $(this).data('user'),
            'seed': $(this).data('seed'),
        };

        $.post(address, input, function(data)
        {
            $fa.addClass('fa-check-circle-o');
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $fa.addClass('fa-exclamation-triangle');
    }
});
```

You can see from the code above, that for each row, I do several things:

- find the nested `.fa` classed element
- check if `process` is true
- collect several pieces of data
- post the data  to the `address`

When the post is finished, it adds a fa-check-circle-o mark to the `.fa` element.

The problem I am having is that all the `.each()` functions run at the same time, instead of one after another. How can I get it to wait to finish each row, before it proceeds to the next row?

I would also like it to add a fa-exclamation-triangle mark to the element on failure, as well as marking `process` as `false` so that it skips all future rows... but I don't know how to catch for failures of the post.

Comment: Try using `promise`  and `resolve`.

Comment: Do you mind explaining that please?

Comment: I would not do this personally, I would send an array to the server and do the processing serverside.

Comment: @JasonAxelrod You can maintain an array of promises and write something like`$(promises).each(function(){
  this.then(function(value){ $fa.addClass('fa-check-circle-o'); }); });` Create the promises in first foreach.

Comment: Do you mind posting an answer with details relevant to my original code?

Comment: You can find about promises here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Comment: That is so confusing... I'm just trying to do a simple thing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply make an array of the elements you want to iterate over and then call them in succession in the ajax callback.  You can use the [Promise interface](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jqxhr-object) here to trigger actions based on the success, failure or completion of your request:

```
var rows;
$(".button").on('click', function() {
    rows = $('.rows').toArray();
    var row = rows.shift();
    doAjax(row);
});
function doAjax(row) {
    $.post('ajax.php')
        .done(function() {
            // this runs on success
        })
        .fail(function() {
            // this runs on ajax failure
        })
        .always(function() {
            // this always runs
            // call next element in your array now...
            if (rows.length) {
                var row = rows.shift();
                doAjax(row);
            }
        });

}
```

Here's a functioning example: http://so-ajax-each.dev.zuma-design.com/

Comment: A nice elegant solution!

Comment: Glad it helped Jason.  I was going to add a word about calling the next  `doAjax()`  inside `.done()` instead of `.always()` if you want to stop iterating on failure but I think you get the idea...

Comment: make sure `rows` is declared in the outermost scope - notice the first row in my example.  that way it's going to be accessible inside the function call

Comment: Alright, fixed that... but now I'm getting the error with `doAjax` inside the always `doAjax is not a function`

Comment: well I can't really guess without seeing your application but I provided a working example in my answer.  it's pretty basic but it demonstrates the concept and generates no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using ECMA6. I am not sure if it is available similarly in ECMA5 also.

```
    var promises = [];
    $target.find('.row').each(function(index)
    {
        var $fa = $(this).find('.fa');

        if (process)
        {
            var input = {
                'eventID': eventID,
                'userID': $(this).data('user'),
                'seed': $(this).data('seed'),
            };

            $.post(address, input, function(data)
            {
                promises[index] = Promises.resolve(data);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $fa.addClass('fa-exclamation-triangle');
        }
    });
    $(promises).each(function(){ 
     this.then(function(value){
        $fa.addClass('fa-check-circle-o');
    });
    });
```

Comment: Getting an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Promises is not defined`

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem of waiting for each request before sending the new one.

Comment: You need to wrap in a promise constructor

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {})

Comment: Also, how do I check to see if the post FAILS, and if it fails, it should set `process` to false... which should skip all remaining rows. Since the check for process is outside of the promise, wouldn't it not be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `async` option as `false` when using jQuery AJAX (I modified your formatting slightly because it was annoying me):

```
$target.find('.row').each(function() {
    var $fa = $(this).find('.fa');

    if (process) {
        var input = {
            'eventID': eventID,
            'userID': $(this).data('user'),
            'seed': $(this).data('seed'),
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: address,
            data: input,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $fa.addClass('fa-check-circle-o');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $fa.addClass('fa-exclamation-triangle');
    }
});
```

Comment: `async:false` is deprecated. In addition, doing so makes it so the `addClass` functions don't show until the end... instead of as it's working.

Comment: Good to know `async` is deprecated. Looks like you may need to try and read up about things like https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ to get this working